# I Can't seem To Use a tinyint value for System.DayOfWeek in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, date-math

I have my "day of the week" for an event stored as a tinyint in SQL Server table.
0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, etc.

When I pull back a row from the database, I need to use that tinyint value but as a System.DayOfWeek value (whatever the heck that is). I have a function provided to me that uses System.DayOfWeek instead of the numbers 0-6. It returns the next day of the week after today that is provided.

```
 public static DateTime Next(this DateTime from, DayOfWeek dayOfTheWeek)
        {
            var date = from.Date.AddDays(1);
            var days = ((int)dayOfTheWeek - (int)date.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
            return date.AddDays(days);
        }
```

It errors saying this about the second argument in my function call: "cannot convert from 'byte' to 'System.DayOfWeek'":

DateTime NextEvent;

NextEvent= WorkingDates.DateTimeExtensions.Next(DateTime.Now.Date, **item.RecurDayOfWeek**);

===========================

At another place in my code close by I try this:

```
System.DayOfWeek thisDayOfWeek;

thisDayOfWeek = item.RecurDayOfWeek;
```

and I get this error when I mouse over the right hand side:
CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte' to 'System.DayOfWeek'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I'd like to believe that the solution would have bit me if it was a snake, but I am totally lost at the moment and hope someone can see an answer.

(item.RecurDayOfWeek is the data from the column in the database)

---

I researched my errors first with the CS code and Microsoft, but the answers were too vague. I also Googled the error messages. Only came here after all failed. It seems so simple and was. I checked the accepted answer.

Comment: "as a System.DayOfWeek value (whatever the heck that is)" - Microsoft has some pretty extensive documentation.

Comment: For example, this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to explicitly convert it:

```
byte dayInByte = 6;
var day = (DayOfWeek)dayInByte;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Next` casts the `dayOfTheWeek` to an int:

```
var days = ((int)dayOfTheWeek ...
```

It looks like you have at least 3 options:

1. Make `Next` accept a number: `Next(this DateTime from, int dayOfTheWeek)`
2. Call `Next` with a cast: `Next(DateTime.Now.Date, (DayOfWeek)item.RecurDayOfWeek);`
3. Add a `Next` overload:

   ```cs
   DateTime Next(this DateTime from, int dayOfTheWeek) 
       => Next(from, (DayOfWeek)dayOfTheWeek);
   ```

---

BTW. You could additionally make `Next` use `DateOnly` to be more precise:

```cs
DateOnly Next(DateOnly from, DayOfWeek dayOfTheWeek)
```